# drawer face connector name - ikea part number 126888 - blum drawer face

Tags: cabinets, connectors

I need to buy a couple of these connectors.  They come from ikea in the godmorgon sets with drawer fronts.  Here is the image.  Any idea of the name so I could search and possibly just buy a couple of these?  I think they are from blum originally as the slides are blum slides.

[image: blum connector]

My custom cabinet guy bought a ninka recycle bin unit for my custom kitchen.  He couldn't figure out how to install it so I ended up putting it together.  The face of the ninka is a panel from the kitchen company it installs using this connector to the ninka hardware (which is blum).  The kitchen company didn't provide these connectors to me or they were lost.  Since the hardware looked the same as the ikea blum godmorgon and I had hacked an ikea godmorgon unit as a sink cabinet and I had an extra draw with a couple of these connectors I salvaged them from the drawer and they worked.  Now I have an ikea drawer that I may use in the future sometime but I don't have the connectors.  Since these seem to be blum connectors or maybe even something more generic to the cabinet world I thought someone might have a name for them such that I could just purchase some.

The general term for the connector is a front fixing bracket.

Comment: I don't think you'll find these anywhere other than IKEA direct, they will be manufactured specifically for them. They don't have a generic name.
There's an eBay listing for some parts in including this, but that part is out of stock.

Comment: In general I think that if your question starts with "I got it from IKEA", then the answer is "go back to IKEA for replacements/spares". The one exception may be: We bought some 8' cabinets and just a few shelves. To add more shelves, we bought simple white melamine boards at the local home center and 5mm shelf support pins. Of course, the IKEA shelf depth was between sizes sold at the big-box, so I had to rip them to width on a table saw. i.e. off-the-shelf parts from somewhere else would _not_ work without modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IKEA have a 'Contact Us' page where you can order spare parts.

For instance [this](https://gbinincontact.ikea.com/CONTACTUS/iSupport.aspx?Country=UK&SaleType=Aftersales&MissingFittings=Yes&CM=b7&Store=SOL&RID=84#Main) is the page I land on in the UK, and there is a section at the bottom where you can enter a part number:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try.

Comment: I was able to order the part and it seems like it was free !